# Run -E without sudo

Tags: sudo, 19.04, root, docker, container

Is there a way to run `sudo -E bash -` without the `sudo` command?

I have the command `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -` that I want to run inside an Ubuntu container where no `sudo` exists. By running it with Docker though I provide the Docker parameter `-u root:sudo` so that everything inside executes as root.

The command `sudo -E bash -` fails though, because `sudo` does not exist. Is there a way to just run `-E bash -`?

Comment: **-E** is a switch for sudo, not a separate command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-E` is an option of the `sudo` command, not a part of the actual command you are running with elevated privileges.

From `man sudo`:

```
 -E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to pre‐
             serve their existing environment variables.  The security
             policy may return an error if the user does not have permis‐
             sion to preserve the environment.
```

So as you don't use `sudo` at all, the environment will not be modified anyway. You don't need to replace this option with anything. Just

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash
```

(Btw. the trailing `-` argument after `bash` has no effect, you can omit that too.)

Whether it is advisable regarding security to directly run unverified code fetched from an online source as root is another question though...

Comment: On the security aspect: [Is `curl {something} | sudo bash -` a reasonably safe installation method?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213401/is-curl-something-sudo-bash-a-reasonably-safe-installation-method)